# Why is FreeMarker IDE in Eclipse Oxygen JBoss Tools 4.5.2.Final deprecated?

Tags: eclipse, jboss, freemarker

I just followed the instructions on how to install the latest freemarker version for my Eclipse IDE. After following the steps given here: https://freemarker.apache.org/editors.html I see in the Red Hat Central window in eclipse under Add Tools That the FreeMarker IDE entry is deprecated.

What does that mean? Will the project not be continued? Is it replaced? If so, by what?

Comment: FYI, I have asked for some details directly from them on the jbosstools-dev mailing list... no answer so far. But I guess their resources are limited and they retire plugins that has become less important for them, so they can focus more on hotter things... I will look into forking it or the like if it will become unavailable from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JBoss Tools Freemarker plugin project was deprecated back in July 2017 [0] because no one was maintaining it, evolving it, or doing anything but infrequently rebuilding it with upversioned plugin/feature versions.

[0] https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-discovery/commit/4f7978ab1ee11dd2a0059b565b06c49b05bcb8df

You can see from the project's commit history [1] it's been very quiet in there for some time:

[1] https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-freemarker/commits/master

So, as of JBoss Tools 4.5.3, it's been removed entirely [2].

[2] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-25736

If you'd like to take ownership and start submitting PRs to keep it current against Eclipse Oxygen.3 (and soon Eclipse Photon.0 too), we could consider bringing it back from the dead. Or you could simply fork it, build it, publish it somewhere, and then submit a new Eclipse Marketplace entry for it, thus taking on the maintenance yourself.

The other reason for its deprecation is that it enjoys very low usage (according to the embedded Usage tracker in JBoss Tools. This might be because people using the Freemarker plugin ONLY install the Freemarker plugin, rather than also installing the rest of JBoss Tools, so that the usage tracking is not enabled. It could also be because Freemarker users opt out of having their usage tracked.

But because we have little data to suggest a thriving community of users, and because the code base itself hasn't changed significantly in over a year, we decided to remove it from JBoss Tools [2] in order to focus on what users actually, provably, use.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't think I have the capacity to maintain it right now. But I'm one of those who use it with the usage statistics disabled.

Comment: I'm not sure about the size of the user base, but people who need this plugin need it because of FreeMarker, and
they have no "relationship" with the other JBoss IDE products, so... as
the installation instructions on apache.freemarker.org say, they only
install the FreeMarker plugin.

Comment: exactly. me and I guess everyone else at my company only uses the freemarker part of JBoss. Never used any other JBoss component

Comment: @tObi if this plugin is critical to you but you don't jave the capacity to maintain it, you can suggest your company to get in touch with Red Hat support to evaluate whether some $$$ or partnership can convince Red Hat to keep working on this plugin.

Comment: The plugin will either continue as a product under the FreeMarker project (at Apache), or if that won't happen (legal issues, etc.) I will just fork it for maintenance. In any case, it's always possible to install it as described at https://freemarker.apache.org/editors.html (not as part of the JBoss Tools from the Eclipse Marketplace anymore).